# How to force iMovie to create iPhoto video thumbnails in the background?

Tags: photos.app, imovie, automation

I import my videos from my camera into iPhoto along with the stills. Then I use iMovie to create videos from them. Unfortunately every time I open iMovie to get some work done it wants to go through and update thumbnails. Sometimes it is quick, but sometimes it takes quite a while.

Is there a way to get iMovie to make these thumbnails in the background so I am not forced to wait when I open it? I know I can skip it, but usually those thumbnails are for the video I want to work on.

Answer (score -1):

Try importing a movie from a DVD.
If you do, that will give your video options just enough complexity, apparently, to cause imovie to give you a choice;  the left navigation should show that importation event along side of your iphoto movies. This happened to me at least. As soon as I imported from other sources, it no longer kept my ENTIRE iphoto library as the default. In reading what I just wrote, I'm now confused: I'm pretty sure that I put my DVD video through iPhoto first, so, I'm not sure exactly what I did in imovie to make the importation event unique, but in any case, once I did that, I wound up seeing a directory structure where my iphotos videos were no longer the default selected.

Of course, in order to use *any* of those videos, I now have to click on iPhoto movies in which case I'm back to waiting for the all to load, which still takes a long time.